# Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number PHP?

Tags: php

I was trying to solve the 8. Question of project euler and I have the following PHP code. But my answer isnt right. What did i do wrong?

```
<?php

$data = '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450';
$greatest = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); $i++) {
  $_data = substr($data, $i, 5);
  if (strlen($_data) == 5) {
    $_product = 1;
    for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
      $_product += $_data[$j];
    }
    if ($_product > $greatest) {
      $greatest = $_product;
    }
  }
}
echo $greatest;

?>
```

Comment: your code is finding a sum and not a product.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to change the following:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
      $_product += $_data[$j]; // Here change the plus sign (+) with a star (*)
   }
```